# Check slider status and click on it only if disabled in cypress

Tags: html, automation, cypress

I need to check the status of the 'md-switch' class button and only if it is unchecked, press it. Otherwise, to move on. How can I use the proper '.check()' method here?

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 form-row wrap-switch-row form-row-border-bottom account-bottom-row">
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-2">
      <div class="md-switch"><input type="checkbox" id="switch-input" name="set-name" formcontrolname="email" class="switch-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-name="email"><label for="switch-input" class="switch-label"><span class="toggle-on"></span><span class="toggle-off"></span></label></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-11 col-10">
      <div class="switch-text-label"> Marketing Emails </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hasClass` jquery method with negation to check that the disabled class is not present, Something like this:

```js
cy.get('div.md-switch').then(($ele) => {
  if(!$ele.hasClass('disabled')){
    //Do something when enabled
  }
  else {
    //Do something when disabled
  }
})
```

if you just want to check one out of the two, you can use the `eq` method. `eq(0)` for the first occurrence and `eq(1)` for the second occurrence.

```js
cy.get('div.md-switch').eq(0).then(($ele) => {
  if(!$ele.hasClass('disabled')){
    //Do something when enabled
  }
  else {
    //Do something when disabled
  }
})
```

If you want to check them both in one go, you can use the `each` method to loop over each occurrence one by one and check for the class.

```js
cy.get('div.md-switch').each(($ele) => {
  if(!$ele.hasClass('disabled')){
    //Do something when enabled
  }
  else {
    //Do something when disabled
  }
})
```

In case you want to make a decision based on the checked/unchecked state of the checkbox you can do this:

```js
cy.get('#switch-input').then(($ele) => {
  if (!$ele.is(':checked')) {
    //Checkbox is unchecked
    cy.wrap($ele).check()
  } else {
    //Do something when the checkbox is checked
  }
})
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are two 'md-switch' on the page, so I have to search for them in turn. I tried first(), but it didn't work. How can I do it differently?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, I tried separately and with each. The last instruction it executes before stopping (without errors) is 
get div.md-switch Does not fit into the if structure as it should